# Outlook 2010 Authenticated RSS Feed

Tags: rss, microsoft-office-2010

I am running Windows 7 x64 with Office 2010. I have a RSS feed on the same domain as my workstation. The feed requires authentication.

I have enabled the 'Synchronize RSS Feeds to the Common Feed List' option within Outlook and verified that this is working. Several default feeds were pulled into Outlook.

I have added a couple custom entries to the feed list in IE. Any time that my customized feeds with their user names and passwords saved are called I am getting an error - 0x800C008, unknown error. The server shows a failed login, indicating that the ID and password are not sticking.

I have also verified that the site in question is listed in the intranet zone so security within IE shouldn't be a problem. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I deleted all the RSS feeds with the associated account and recreated the lot. Apparently the name is cached in some fashion beyond just a 1:1 association with the specific feed.